# C# dynamic operators, and substituting for the lack of dynamics in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, dynamic, xamarin.ios, operator-overloading

I am writing some code that would really benefit from the use of "dynamics" in C#. In this code, I could be given a set of objects of various different types, but *each of them has access to the "+" operator and they can each be properly summed together*. For example, it could be a List collection that contains elements of various types: double, float, Int32, UInt16, etc. etc. etc.

Using dynamics I could easily calculate the sum of all these objects using code like the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Int32 w = 5;
    double x = 8.3;
    float y = 19.6f;
    UInt32 z = 2;

    List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
    list.Add(w);
    list.Add(x);
    list.Add(y);
    list.Add(z);
    var result = list.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);

    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result.ToString("0.##"));
}
```

Unfortunately, due to iOS's limitation on code generation at runtime, code similar to the above would not work on iOS because dynamics aren't available in Xamarin iOS.

I am trying to find a way that I can accomplish something similar without the use of dynamics.

I can't do the following because it will result in compile-time errors:

```
List<object> list2 = new List<object>();
list2.Add(w);
list2.Add(x);
list2.Add(y);
list2.Add(z);
list2.Sum();                      //Compile-time error
list2.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b); //Compile-time error
```

Also, I'm looking for a solution that can handle really any object, not just the simple numeric types, as long as the objects override the "+" operator. Obviously you cannot add together any two objects that override the "+" - that's not the point. If two objects exist in the list that cannot be added together, I'll catch the exception and handle it appropriately. But I'd like to be able to handle a scenario like the following as well:

```
List<dynamic> list3 = new List<dynamic>();
list3.Add(DateTime.Now);
list3.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
list3.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: In any case you will have to handle some types manually. E.g. neither int nor string provide plus operator overload. Compiler for int produces Add IL instruction, for strings it will call String.Concat. And when you write 1 + "2", compiler generates String.Concat(1.ToString, "2"). But it is possible to write a generic code for the rest - for types which provide plus operator overload, just using reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I *think* that I've discovered a way to do what I've discussed in my question above. It has been quite a journey.

A lot of people have posted previously about "generic arithmetic operators" in C#, which of course isn't possible in C#. Most of those previous questions have been answered with the following two responses:

1. Use dynamics - which I cannot do, because C# dyanmics won't work on iOS.
2. Use the "MiscUtil" library (which is old, but a Xamarin-compatible version can be found here: https://github.com/HelloKitty/Generic.Math)

The MiscUtil library seemed like it would do the trick, but alas it didn't work either. In my scenario I am given a `List<object>`, and I simply need to sum everything in the list. I know for certain that everything in the list is a numeric type (such as `Int32` or `double`, etc etc etc), but they are given to me as `object`.

The following line of code threw an exception when I tried passing two objects:

`var result = my_list.Aggregate((a, b) => Generic.Math.GenericMath.Add(a, b));`

So the MiscUtil library (also known as GenericMath in its latest form) doesn't work.

**But** I found something that *does* seem to work: Lua. Or more specifically: the NLua library (http://nlua.org/)

NLua indicates that it supports iOS (so I assume whatever it's doing under the hood is not against Apple's rules), and it also indicates it supports Xamarin. Using NLua, I was able to do this:

```
NLua.Lua state = new NLua.Lua();
var result = my_list.Aggregate((a, b) =>
{
    state["x"] = a;
    state["y"] = b;
    var res = state.DoString("return x + y")[0];
    return res;
});
```

And it worked! It even worked when I passed it a `DateTime` object as one parameter and a `TimeSpan` object as another parameter, so it seems like it can adapt very well.

It looks like I'll simply be including NLua in my C# Xamarin Forms project, because it does the trick!